# Inflate method's exception for custom view in android

Tags: android

I'm coding custom control for android and i have confused with next issue:
When I try to invoke `View.inflate()` static method (look at code bellow) I get the runtime exception `android.view.InflateException`.
There is the code for my view

```
public class NavigationView extends RelativeLayout implements NewRadioConst {
      private TextView centerLabel;
      private Context context;
      private Typeface font;
      private ImageView leftArrow;
      private TextView leftLabel;
      private View leftWrapper;
      private ImageView rightArrow;
      private TextView rightLabel;
      private View rightWrapper;

      public NavigationView(Context paramContext)
      {
        this(paramContext, null);
      }

      public NavigationView(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet)
      {
        this(paramContext, paramAttributeSet, 0);
      }

      public NavigationView(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet, int paramInt)
      {
        super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet, paramInt);
        this.context = paramContext;
        View.inflate(context, R.id.navView1, this);  //this line take the exception
      }

}
```

And here is the xml that I try to inflate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navView1" >
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/centerWrapper" android:layout_centerInParent="true" style="@style/WrapContent">
        <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/centerBg" android:layout_width="90.0dip" android:layout_height="30.0dip" android:src="@drawable/center_bg" />
        <TextView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/centerLabel" android:text="@string/music" style="@style/TextLabel" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/leftWrapper" android:clickable="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" style="@style/WrapContent">
        <TextView android:textSize="12.0dip" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/leftLabel" android:layout_marginLeft="8.0dip" android:text="@string/info" android:singleLine="true" style="@style/TextLabel" />
        <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/leftArrow" android:layout_width="50.0dip" android:layout_height="30.0dip" android:src="@drawable/left_arrow" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rightWrapper" android:clickable="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" style="@style/WrapContent">
        <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/rightArrow" android:layout_width="50.0dip" android:layout_height="30.0dip" android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" />
        <TextView android:textSize="12.0dip" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@+id/rightLabel" android:layout_marginRight="8.0dip" android:text="@string/news" android:singleLine="true" style="@style/TextLabel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is logcat

```
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.groupab.newradio/com.groupab.newradio.MusicActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.groupab.newradio.view.NavigationView
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.groupab.newradio.view.NavigationView
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at com.polontech.android.newradio.MusicActivity.onCreate(MusicActivity.java:12)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     ... 11 more
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     ... 21 more
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:147)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:121)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at com.groupab.newradio.view.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:41)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     at com.groupab.newradio.view.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:33)
03-08 11:37:00.585: E/AndroidRuntime(2374):     ... 24 more
```

Comment: @bleckbelt hang on a moment

Comment: according to stack trace, something went wrong while loading custom typeface. Make sure that path to the font is written correctly and the font file isn't corrupted

Answer (score 0):

The inflate method is expecting a layout id of the form: R.layout.XXX.  I would remove the id identifier navView1 from the top level element and reference the name of the xml layout file instead. So if you named the xml layout file navView1, you would simple reference as R.layout.navView1.